# To prove - cover of union of backwards orbits of tent map is I

Tags: dynamical-systems

I read, that

$$
\overline{\bigcup^\infty_{n=0} T^{-n}(0)} = I,
$$

(where $T$ is [Tent map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tent_map) and $I = [0; 1]$) but I don't understand why.

Could you, please, show me the proof of this?

Comment: Sure, that $I$ is the identity here? This does not make any sense. I'd say $I = [0,1]$, the unit interval.

Comment: @martini Thank you very much! Of course it's the unit closed interval.

Comment: And you want the unit-height tent?

Comment: @martini That was not specified in the book, but I suppose so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $T^{-1}(\{0\}) = \{0,1\}$. To compute the higher inverse images, note, that $T^{-1}(\{x\}) = \{\frac x2,1-\frac x2\}$ for $x\in[0,1]$. Therefore 
$$ T^{-2}(\{0\}) = \left\{0,\frac 12, 1\right\} $$
By induction, we see that 
$$ T^{-n}(\{0\}) = \left\{  \frac{k}{2^{n-1}} : k =  0,\ldots, 2^{n-1}\right\}$$
This gives us that $\bigcup_n T^{-n}(\{0\})$ consists of all dyadic fractions, which form a dense subset of $[0,1]$.

Comment: So if I understand it well, $\bigcup^\infty_{n=0} T^{-n}(0) = \overline{\bigcup^\infty_{n=0} T^{-n}(0)} = I$?

Comment: No, only the closure equals $I$, for example $\frac 13$, not being a dyadic rational, does not belong to any $T^{-n}[\{0\}]$